# Is there any difference between db.Categories and List<Category>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

The following code works good

```
IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> groupList = db.Categories.Select(p => new GroupedSelectListItem()
{
     GroupKey = p.ParentCategory.Name,
     GroupName = p.ParentCategory.Name,
     Text = p.Name,
     Value = p.Name
});
```

While the below code generates **object reference not set to an instance error**

```
List<Category> orderedList = new List<Category>();
var rootList = db.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == null).ToList();
    foreach (var item in rootList)
    {
        orderedList.Add(item);
        if (item.SubCategories.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var subcat in item.SubCategories)
            {
                orderedList.Add(subcat);
                if (subcat.SubCategories.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var subsubcat in subcat.SubCategories)
                    {
                        orderedList.Add(subsubcat);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> groupList = orderedList.Select(p => new GroupedSelectListItem()
{
     GroupKey = p.ParentCategory.Name,
     GroupName = p.ParentCategory.Name,
     Text = p.Name,
     Value = p.Name
});
```

**Error Detail**

> Line 54:             IEnumerable groupList = orderedList.Select(p => new GroupedSelectListItem()

**NOTE:** The table for Categories in database contains element with ParentCategoryId for some records equal to null

Comment: What about showing where exactly did you get null reference exception ...

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, sorry I am not well versed in debugging and tracing, but i have added the red line text showed with the error message in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet is using Linq-to-entities with automatic coalescence. It menas that if p doesn't have `ParentCategory` it will work without problem on SQL level. The second example use Linq-to-objects where no such feature exists. You must manually check if `ParentCategory` property is filled prior to accessing its properites:

```
GroupKey = p.ParentCategory != null ? p.ParentCategory.Name : null
```